# Sort Lines In A StringBuilder

Tags: c#, sorting, stringbuilder

How can one alphabetically sort the lines of a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: sort them before you put them in a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't care about the performance, you can do something like this:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("3333");
    sb.AppendLine("2222");
    sb.AppendLine("1111");

    List<string> items = new List<string>(sb.ToString().Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    items.Sort();
    sb = new StringBuilder(string.Join("\r\n", items.ToArray()));
```

Comment: If you don't care about performance: needs more [`stacksort`](http://gkoberger.github.io/stacksort/) ;p

Comment: What is the point of having the first string builder if you're just going to overwrite it?

Comment: @Asad: he stated that he already has the StringBuilder, so.... I think that the answer matches the question...

Comment: Yes, but the OP can just insert the sorting code before their string builder code. Why would they need to keep the original string builder *and* create an entirely new one?

Comment: @Asad: that's true, but in the question OP says that the input for the sort is a StringBuilder, and if you are reading between the lines he is expecting a StringBuilder as result. So... I still think that the answer matches the question :) Other than that, I agree and I would never use this approach.

Comment: I thought there are some Stringbuilder option to sort the data, but finally I have refactored the code to use list at the beggining in the place of StringBuilder. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`StringBuilder` is *basically* a wrapper over pending character data (either a mutable hidden `string`, or a `char[]`, depending on the implementation). As such, you can't sort it internally - or at least, not very easily. Your best bet is to either:

- put the lines into a `List<string>` or some other collection *first*, then sort and combine
- perform a `string.Split()`, sort the array, and re-combine

The first is potentially more efficient. An even better way would be to find a way to *sort the source data*, so that it is sorted before you even start building strings.

Comment: Does `StringBuilder` actually use an honest-to-goodness mutable string? I thought it was just an abstraction over a character stream that got concatenated into a string when `ToString`d.

Comment: @Asad yes, in the Microsoft BCL implementation, it uses an honest-to-goodness mutable string. You might *think* that it uses a character stream, but no.

Comment: @Asad I don't think it does anymore, actually.  I'm pretty sure it was just the pre 4.0 version that did that.

Comment: @Servy dammit, yeah, looks like it moved to a `char[] chunkChars`. Where's the joy in playing by the rules? It used to be the `string m_StringValue`, which was great fun

Comment: @MarcGravell Well, if it makes you fell better, the `ToString` *does* mutate an actual `string` object when its building it, it just doesn't hold onto a mutable reference for the life of the `StringBuilder`.  It creates and mutates a reference during the scope of the `ToString` Method rather than building up a `char[]` that it needs to copy into a strings internal buffer.